# Oracle SQL Query to get exact last 30/31/28 days from sysdate

Tags: oracle

I want a simple SQL query to get the dates between sysdate and exact 30 days behind.

For ex: Today is March 12, 2014 then the date should be between 13 Feb, 2014 to march 12, 2014.

I cannot do the simply -30 days because in this case I will Feb 10th, 2014. But I don't want in this way. Please suggest me if you have any idea.

I am using Oracle 11g version.

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  Please clarify your question, and show what you have tried.

Comment: I want the exact 1 month difference.

Comment: try [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/684ba/3) fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ADD_MONTHS function and use -1 as the months to add, as below:

```
select ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1)
from dual;
```

Here are [some examples](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/add_months.php).

Comment: Although the question is not clear, but I do not think add_months consider the leap years, for example add_months -1 for 12 march always return 12 feb for leap years and for not a leap years.

Comment: @Eng.SamerT leap year has no impa